# Multiple URLs in uri module

Tags: ansible, uri

consider this ansible code

```
- name: Retrieve the wf execution information
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get execution info
      uri: 
        url: https://myurl
        user: my_user
        password: my_pass
        method: GET
        return_content: yes
      register: wf_runs
      notify:
        - pager-duty
      changed_when: True

    - name: Print all the runs of the wf
      debug: 
        var: wf_runs.json.relations.link | last

    - name: Assign the variable
      set_fact:
        last_run: "{{ wf_runs.json.relations.link | last }}"

  handlers:
    - name: pager-duty
      pagerduty_alert:
        api_key: my-key
        integration_key: xxxxx
        service_id: sss
        state: triggered
        desc: 
          - "Job started at: {{ last_run | json_query('attributes[1].value')\n }}"
          - "Job ended at: {{ last_run | json_query('attributes[2].value')\n }}"
          - "Job status: {{ last_run | json_query('attribuets[5].value')\n }}"
```

I want to run the same code against 4 different urls and 4 different environments, like so

```
https://myurl-env1-wf2
https://myurl-env1-wf3
```

How can I achieve that? I have tried looping through the urls but it fails at `wf_runs.json.relations.lil | last` as undefined variable. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Q:*"I want to run the same code against 4 different urls"*

A: Put the tasks into a file and add *meta: flush_handlers*. For example

```
$ cat get-info-handle-allert.yml
- name: Get execution info
  uri: 
    url: "{{ item }}"
  ...
- name: Print all the runs of the wf
  ...
- name: Assign the variable
  ...
- meta: flush_handlers
```

Loop [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list). For example

```
  tasks:
    - name: Loop get-info-handle-allert
      include_tasks: get-info-handle-allert.yml
      loop:
        - https://myurl
        - https://myurl-env1-wf2
        - https://myurl-env1-wf3
```

(not tested. If there is a problem with flush_handlers just replace the *meta* task with the task from the handler.)